# Converting Intent to Fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

In general most of the time I work with Intent rather than Fragment because I found It somehow complex. I have a class with ListView to show some data from an array and I want to convert it in Fragment also want to pass the extras in a new fragmented class.

ListView Class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView list;
    String[] web = { "Google", "Twitter", "Windows", "Bing", "Itunes",
            "Wordpress", "Drupal" };
    Integer[] imageId = { R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CustomList adapter = new CustomList(MainActivity.this, web, imageId);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "You Clicked at " + web[+position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();


                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, intent.class);
                i.putExtra("name", web[+position]);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

CustomList Class:

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] web;
    private final Integer[] imageId;

    public CustomList(Activity context, String[] web, Integer[] imageId) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_single, web);
        this.context = context;
        this.web = web;
        this.imageId = imageId;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        txtTitle.setText(web[position]);

        imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

I got a main class with three tabs created using fragment and in this class I would like to add the ListView!

```
public class LayoutOne extends Fragment {


    public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
        LayoutOne f = new LayoutOne();  

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_one, null);
        return root;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

}
```

What I want to do is to show the listview in the fragment class and when a list item will be click I want to launch the New Intent to show which Item was clicked!

Comment: i think the fragment is just a found-in-web-fragment-copy&paste-dummy

Comment: It's not a singleton @Neil, that's an official design pattern to create a fragment and pass it arguments.

Comment: You learn something new every day. I've never used it before.

Comment: I used fragment because I wanted to created tabs with swipe view! On my main activity class I got three tabs and these one is one of them. I want to show the ListView on my first tab!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass parameters into a Fragment, common practice is to create a static method that produces an instance of your Fragment with certain parameters.  You already have the `newInstance` method, now you just need to add parameters to the arguments and return the Fragment.  You should check for the arguments in your `onCreateView` The following is an example of how you would write one.

```java
public class LayoutOne extends Fragment 
{

    public static Fragment newInstance(int someInt, String someString) 
    {
        LayoutOne f = new LayoutOne();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("someInt", someInt);
        args.putString("someString", someString);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_one, null);
        Bundle args = getArguments();

        //From here you would check to see if your arguments are present 
        //proceed accordingly

        return root;

    }
}
```

For your specific case, you could pass along the String array and add it as an argument.

Hope this helps.  Good luck!

**Edit**

The problem you're facing is that you're instantiating a `ListView` in your `Activity` when in reality you should be doing it in your `Fragment`.  Intents aren't needed here, you just need to make sure that there is a `ListView` attribute to get from the layout you attach to your `Fragment`.  The following is a small example of how that should work.

Note, this method goes in your `LayoutOne` class

```java
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_one, null);

    //Be sure to use the actual id of your list view
    ListView lv = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.list_view_id);

    //Make sure that you retrieve the values for 'web' and 'imageId' from 
    //the activity using the "newInstance" method.
    CustomList adapter = new CustomList(getActivity(), web, imageId);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    //From here, set your onClickListener and stuff as you did in your Activity

    return root;

}
```

As a note, `Fragment`s don't have the `findViewById` method.  You have to call it on the `View` that you are inflating to be its layout, so in this case you inflated `root` and then you would call `root.findViewById(R.id.some_id)` to get a view.

Comment: I'm having errors! Please re-check my code to understand what I actually mean! @Andrew Schuster

Comment: #1 - The constructor CustomList(LayoutOne, String[], Integer[]) is undefined 
#2 - The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type LayoutOne 
#3 - The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (LayoutOne, String, int)

Comment: The first error is a problem I can't help you with.  That's an issue in your implementation of `CustomList`.  I addressed the second error in my edit above.  The third doesn't work because `Fragments` don't extend Context.  Put `Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "your text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()` instead

Comment: thanks a lot! your code fixes two problems already! now I need to make the onClickListener working for ListView. I'm using the same onClickListener from ListView class, Its not showing any error but the app crashes with onClickListener enabled! any idea? @Andrew Schuster

Comment: You have to check the LogCat in order to see the errors caused by crashing.  Find the LogCat and you will know your error. @ProkashSarkar